# How to install jGroups for NetBeans 6.7.1

Tags: netbeans, jgroups

Newbie question - I am using NetBeans 6.7.1 (just installed it) and wanted to write an application using jGroups ...

From the sample I need to import org.jgroups.*, but in NetBeans I get the following error:
   package org.jgroups does not exist

So, went on the net and download jGroups (src and bin), been trying to figure out how to get it to work but nothing I do seems to solve the problem.

Anyone able to point me in the right direction? What files do I put where and what do I need to change in NetBeans so that it starts to work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You need to add jGroups as a NetBeans library.

From the menus, select `Tools > Libraries`. (Note in older releases it was called `Tools > Component Libraries`.)

Click "`New Library...`"

For `Library Name`, enter a name for the library. Eg: `jGroups`

For `Library Type`, select `Class Libraries`

Click `OK`

Select the `Classpath` tab and add the jGroups jar(s) using the `Add JAR/Folder...` button.

Likewise, use the `Sources` tab and `Javadoc` tab to add the sources (for debugging) and the JavaDocs (for auto popup documentation). If you don't have the source and/or JavaDoc, it will still give you code completion, just not the documentation of debugging.

All of that defines jGroups as a library and makes it available to NetBeans.

Now, got to you project's properties. Choose `Libraries`, click `Add Library...` and select the jGroups library.